# Get the next enumerated item after applying a predicate via Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for an elegant way to return the next enumerated item.

Let's say I have this collection:

```
IEnumerable<int> collection = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

And this predicate:

```
Func<int,bool> pred = i => i == 5;
```

I want to run the predicate and then get the next item.
I'd like to use a method like this:

```
var item = collection.GetNextItem(pred); // 6
```

I know there are numerous ways to code it (via `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext`) but I was wondering if there is a Linq method that already does it, or any other elegant Linq trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SkipWhile`:

```
var item = collection.SkipWhile(i => i != 5).Skip(1).First();
```

This skips all items that *don't* match the predicate, then skips the one matching and then takes the first of the remaining items.

If your `pred` is predefined and you can't change it, you can call `SkipWhile` like that:

```
var item = collection.SkipWhile(i => !pred(i)).Skip(1).First();
```